# finding a solution to a matrix inequality

Tags: matrices, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I would like to find a 19x19 matrix V such that the following inequality holds:
$$V^TAV<K$$
and where all entries of V are positive and the sum of entires in a row of V are equal to 1.
Also < is taken point wise and K and A are particular matrices specified by the problem. In particular, the ij<sup>th</sup> element of A is sign(j-i) where sign(x)=|x|/x for x≠0 and 0 for x=0.

K has the following property:

The diagonal of K is all 0's and each other entry of K is either a 1 or e where 0 < e << 1. Also Kij = 1 iff Kji = e.

Although for my specific problem there are some additional properties satisfied by A and K, I am interested in more general approaches to solving problems of this form.

So far, the best idea for solving this is to use gradient descent. In particular I was considering picking a random matrix V, then computing Q as follows:

$$Q=V^TAV-K$$

Then let $$err = ∑_{i,j} max(Qij,0) $$

and then I would try to minimize err via gradient descent

Comment: How would gradient descent work in this situation?

Comment: I would hopefully get an ever smaller err as a descend the gradient, if I reached an error of 0 then we know that Q≤0 and thus the problem has been solved

Comment: please note that I was simply giving an example of what I have tried so far, I am not claiming this is a good idea nessisarily

Comment: Oh I see. So instead of minimizing err, you were attempting to make it exactly 0? Hmm.

Comment: Can you describe $A$ a little bit better? "the ijth element of A is 1 when ij" is not very clear to me.

Comment: @FXV thanks for pointing out the lack of clarity, I have improved my question (hopefully)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you are in dimension $n$. If the lines of $V$ are $(v_1' \ldots v_n')$, then:
$$V'AV=(\langle v_i,Av_j \rangle)$$
If you write $v_i=\sum_k v_{ik}e_k$, you also have:
$$ \langle e_k,Ae_l \rangle =1_{k<l}-1_{k>l}$$
Thus:
$$ \langle u_i,Au_j \rangle =\sum_{k,l} u_{ik} u_{jl} \langle e_k,Ae_l \rangle =\sum_{k<l} u_{ik} u_{jl} - \sum_{k>l} u_{ik} u_{jl} $$

In particular, you can see that all the coefficients are smaller than $1$ in absolute value, and that the matrix is antisymmetric (so its diagonal is zero).

Finally, thanks to this formula, if you take $V=\left(\frac1n\right)$ (with all coefficients equal to $\frac1n$), you have $V'AV=0$, which is a solution to your problem.

You can also find a constant $c$ (at least close to $1/2$ for $e$ close to $0$) such that any other matrix $\tilde V$ with $|\tilde V-V|< ce$ remains a solution.